# Failing to Log Into Umbraco admin Area

Tags: .net, authentication, umbraco

Hi Guys I have inherited an Umbraco site but I am getting a splash screen informing me that

*"Looks like there's still work to do".*

I am getting three errors in the console which my have somthing to do with this;

[image]

Microsoft SQL Server is telling me that there is content on the site

I am also struggling to log into the admin area.

could this be an error connecting to the database?

I have checked the credentials and all seems good, no error messages are being displayed.

My admin credentials are also correct as

*I have reset my password hash*

*set userEnabled to True*

*and tried to log in with other users*

Below is the failed login page I am being redirected to;

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated

Regards

Comment: This seems like a db or upgrade error. Did you upgrade your site? Is your connectionstring correct? And can you see a Umbraco version number in app settings in web.config?

Comment: Hi Morten, A fellow employee upgraded the site, the connection string is correct ( the SQL user is the database owner ), the Umbraco version is value="4.5.2". Regards

Comment: ok, so its properly a problem related to the upgrade. Is 4.5.2 the upgraded version or the old version? Try to check if dlls and /config files are correct for this specific version. Also, check log in App_data/logs for errors and post them here.

Comment: Hi Morten, I have discovered the issue, The problem was that in my connection key <add name="umbracoDbDSN" > the server should have been set to   ./SQLEXPRESS . To anyone viewing this please make sure you check both your connection string and connection key! both in to be found in your web.config

Comment: PS Morten Please add my solution as an answer and I will mark it correct. Regards

Comment: jmack cool it works now! I created an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your connectionstring is correct and the version number in web.config match the current umbraco version.